# How to listen to [Android phone's music] from [a headphone that is connected to a Windows 10 desktop] without internet connection?

Tags: windows-10, audio, android, bluetooth, a2dp

How to listen to music without internet connection from Android phone (Pixel 3a) on Windows 10 when wearing headphone using bluetooth or usb?

I have Pixel 3a as my phone and I have installed YouTube Music on it.

I want to be able to wear my headphone, which is connected to my Windows 10 PC desktop and listen to both my desktop's audio (for example, PC game sound) and my Pixel 3a's music.

How can I achieve this?

Note:

- I searched on the internet and it seems like [Windows 10 doesn't have bluetooth support by default that support audio streaming from phone to PC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/unable-to-stream-music-from-android-to-windows-10/4ebf16ed-30b7-4483-99d6-90643ecdd150?page=4). People seems to be able to install a different bluetooth driver and get it to work, but I can't get it to work. (if you can get it to work please list the exact step)
- [This source](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3a-9408.php) says Pixel 3a has A2DP.

Comment: Both pixel 3a and desktop are own by me in my house

Comment: What is the meaning of the brackets in the title?

Comment: I used the bracket to let people know that I mean "Android phone's music" instead of something else like "Android phone's music from a headphone" because depend on how you break the sentence, you can have different interpretation of a sentence.